# jeditable on a label, how do I keep it from losing focus on click?

Tags: jquery, events, jeditable

I'm building a simple script that allows a user to add telephone numbers dynamically. These are inputs paired with a labels which can all be edited on the fly. I'm using jeditable for the labels but then I've come across a small problem, if a user tries to click inside the input box of the label the browser will detect a click on the label and place the focus on the input element of the label's "for" attribute.

I tried the following:

```
$(selector).find('input').live('focus', function(){
    $(selector).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault;
        return false;
    });
}).live('blur', function(){
    //somehow reattach the behaviour here?
});
```

Essentially "selector" holds the selector for my jeditable label. I find the input inside of it and on focus I disabled the default behaviour of the label. This keeps the label from changing the focus. However, I do not know how to undo this. I supposed I could toggle a boolean flag and then call seperate method that would prevent the default but I have a feeling that there must be a much cleaner way to do this, any suggestions?

Comment: use a global `var` and a if statement to act as a toggle, as you cannot change `e.preventDefault();` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to remove the `for` attribute when the label is being edited, and then add that attribute back after the editing.

```
// store the "for" attr in the element's data
$('label').each(function() {
    $(this).data('for', $(this).attr('for'));
});

$('label').editable('...', {
    ...
    onreset: function() {
        var $label = $(this).parent();
        $label.attr('for', $label.data('for'));
    }
}).click(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('for');
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/G8QuA/.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason onreset wasn't getting triggered but I managed to do the same thing using the "callback" event instead.